# How to markup a complex status indicator in HTML5?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm currently trying to come up with a good and accessible way to format a status indicator which should be rendered within a set of wizard-like pages on a website. The website should provide a multipage form with a status indicator on top of it as demonstrated in the wireframe below:

[image]

Given the new [progress](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-progress-element)-tag in HTML my first thought was to do something like this:

```
<progress value="2" max="3">
    <ul>
        <li>Beginning</li>
        <li class="now">Right now</li>
        <li>End</li>
    </ul>
</progress>
```

... but since <progress> only accepts phrasing content using a list is not really an option. So right now I would probably go with something like this, integratinng the ARIA [progressbar](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#progressbar)-role:

```
<ul aria-role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="2" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="3" aria-describedby="state2" aria-valuetext="Right now">
    <li id="state1">Beginning</li>
    <li id="state2" class="now">Right now</li>
    <li id="state3">End</li>
</ul>
```

But again, I'm not really sure if the progressbar role can be applied in such a way to a list.

Another problem is, that <progress> is rendered as progress bar in Opera, for instance, so >progress> itself is probably not really a viable solution altogether :-(

Can anyone perhaps recommend an accessible status bar that does *not* only rely on using a single image?

### Current solution

For now I will go with following markup:

```
<section class="progress">
    <h1 class="supportive">Your current progress</h1>
    <ol>
        <li><span class="supportive">Completed step:</span> Login</li>
        <li class="now"><span class="supportive">Current step:</span> Right now</li>
        <li><span class="supportive">Future step:</span> End</li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

All elements of the class "supportive" will be positioned off-screen. IMO this way we should have a nice compromise of semantic markup (the state succession is in my opinion really an ordered list ;-)) and accessibility thanks to the additional header and status text for each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [whatwg](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/content-models.html#table-aria-weak), you're not supposed to assign `progressbar` role to `<ul>` elements.

I'd just ditch `<ul>` and describe progress using (surprise) phrasing content:

```
<section role="status">
    <h2>Task Progress</h2>
    <p>You're now at <progress value=2 max=3>"Right now" step</progress>.
</section>
```

**Update:** You're right, `progress` doesn't suit here, it's more like an interactive form widget. I should've checked first, before taking it from your first example. But anyway, the point is there's no need to use a list (even more so, unordered list), when you can just describe what's going on in plain text. In the case that the list of past and future steps is necessary, I'd just add two more paragraphs, one before the status (‘You've completed the "Beginning" step’), and one after (‘Next step will be the "End" step’).

However, I admit that this isn't a complete answer to your question.

---

Also, I'd say some aria attributes look redundant to me. For example, [`aria-valuetext`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-valuetext) perhaps would make more sense in the context of interactive widget, when there's no other human-friendly description of its state. Though I may be wrong here.

Comment: So basically you would just markup the current state using progress Sounds like a plan to me. Thank you :-) The point of the additional aria-valuetext was that I wanted to provide a natural language output for current state and not only the numeric value which valuenow would produce. I'll try to rephrase the original question and provide some wireframes to better demonstrate my actual problem :-)

Comment: Yep, I think this markup is better from the point of accessibility. Those progress indicators that are so common in wizards (take a look at Amazon's checkout process for example) do look good on screens, but I *guess* they "sound" nonsense for those who don't see it. (BTW, Amazon uses not even a list, but a plain image—one for each step. Also may be suitable, saves you from much markup, and you can just put status text into `alt`.)

Comment: OK, thank you :-) Going with a pure image solution won't work in my case (due to maintenance issues) but I'm confident now that I will come up with a suitable solution thanks to your input :-)

Comment: No probs =) Regarding `aria-valuetext`, I see the purpose, but isn't natural language output already provided in user-friendly form by `li.now`, which is referenced by `aria-describedby`? Though I'm not specialist in this area; maybe such redundancy is useful for screen readers.

Comment: I'm not really convinced that aria-describedby really does that hence I also added the valuetext :-) The problem with <progress> in general is, that it is automatically rendered as progress bar in Opera (which was a bit of a surprise I have to admit :-)). Given that I have to re-open this question, sorry :-)

Comment: You're right, I've updated the post. The problem is interesting, I hope there will be better answers.

Comment: After your last update I'm convinced that we are already on the right track :-) I will update my original post with the solution I will use for now. Sorry for playing ping-pong with your points ;-)